# Yarn: How to change install a local package using .yarnrc files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

- I was looking at this link [Use different registries in yarn and npm](https://medium.com/@crysfel/using-different-registries-in-yarn-and-npm-766541d6f851)
- So let's say I want to use my own version some npm package called **package** instead of installing it using 
  `yarn add package`
- If my folder path is `C:/custom-package`
- I tried to put in my .yarnrc something like `registry "https://package.dev/repository/npm-proxy/" "C:/custom-package/`
- Then run `yarn add package`
- Still didn't work, it installs the normal package as if I'm using `yarn add package`

So the question is: How can I do that, what am I missing?

Comment: so, `yarn add package` installs just like using `yarn add package` - seems like that's right - since you read that link, I take it you've done what's required? ... i.e. *setup an internal npm server in your local network*

Comment: Nope, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: You need to *setup an internal npm server in your local network* - as the article you followed states

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.